# How to create SOAP over JMS in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, soap, spring-boot

There are awesome tutorials for enabling JMS in spring boot and also there are tutorials to create Providers and Consumers of SOAP.

Can someone provide a step by step instruction on how to specify JMS as SOAP transport protocol and where does the JMS implementation live.

Is it: (SOAP + JMS) server vs client server, or client -> jms -> soap server?

Please explain how to create a working example.